# PHP Select from MySQL where date field is 7 days in the future

Tags: mysql

I have an automatic checker that checks for domains that are going to expire within the next 7 days and it sends and email to the customer.

Im using this SQL Query:

```
SELECT * from domain_names where status = '' or status = 'valid' and expiry_date = DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

but its not working correctly. i need it to check for rows with an expiry_date that is 7 days in the future exactly. also if the checker stops running and it misses some rows for the amount of time its not running it needs to do those rows too

Comment: Define "not working correctly". Are you sure you want `status='' or (status='valid' and expiry_date='...')`?

Comment: You probably just want to compare date part and not time.

Comment: what's the type of `expiry_date`? date, or datetime?

Answer (score 2):

You've probably defined `expiry_date` as a datetime value, which means your comparisons are incorrect. e.g. you need to use

```
SELECT ... WHERE date(expiry_date) = date(now() + interval 7 day)
```

instead (note the wrapping of the +7 day in a `date()` operation.

e.g.

Given a table with a date and a datetime field:

```
+------------+---------------------+
| d          | dt                  |
+------------+---------------------+
| 2013-06-28 | 2013-06-28 08:23:03 |
+------------+---------------------+
```

Notice how the comparison comes out:

```
mysql> select d=now(), d=date(now()), dt=now(), dt=date(now()), now() from x;
+---------+---------------+----------+----------------+---------------------+
| d=now() | d=date(now()) | dt=now() | dt=date(now()) | now()               |
+---------+---------------+----------+----------------+---------------------+
|       0 |             1 |        0 |              0 | 2013-06-28 08:26:20 |
+---------+---------------+----------+----------------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

date v.s. datetime = false
date v.s date = true
datetime v.s. datetime = false  (hh:mm:ss doesn't match, so not equal)
datetime v.s. date = false  (date is expanded out to yyyy-mm-hh 00:00:00 and the hh:mm:ss don't match

Comment: works great - how about if the checker stops running and it misses one of the domains and starts running again the next day? it wont pickup the domains?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use parentheses with your `and`/`or` conditions

```
SELECT * from domain_names 
where (status = '' or status = 'valid')
and expiry_date = curdate() + INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

or use `in` in your case

```
SELECT * from domain_names 
where status in ('', 'valid')
and expiry_date = curdate() + INTERVAL 7 DAY
```

Comment: Well, you don't know. He might want what he wrote.

Comment: If you think about it and read the question description I am pretty sure I am right.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your expiry date is a correct datetime field

```
expiry_date=DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

more reliable than

```
expiry_date=DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Actually thinking about it if you want exactly 7 days in the future you'd have to use a datediff too

Something like this to return only requests where the expiry date is exactly 7 days from today.

```
DATEDIFF(expiry_date,DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY))=7
```

Though this isn't fool proof you're better off letting it check against all days between now and 7 days in the future and then if it is setting an "email sent" flag in your database so then you can confirm the email was actually sent rather than blindly trusting a script to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

This should give the result as you need:

```
DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) = expiry_date;
```

You can refer to the link below for more details:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

If you need to advise the rows missed during the checker stops running, meaby you should use a extra tag to indicate if the domain have been advise or not. 
After that, you must select all the rows with date lower than now + 7 days and tag as "not advised".
After sending the email tag it as "advised". And when they re-new the domain tag back as "not advise".

Answer (score -4):

```
$date=date('Y-m-d');
$date=date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date . ' + 7 day'));


//Now, use this query.

SELECT * from domain_names where status = '' or status = 'valid' and expiry_date = '{$date}';
```

Comment: -1 for using php time operations instead of directly in mysql, plus I'd make it -2 for generating invalid timestings to begin with.

Comment: The question is tagged under PHP.

yeah date('Y-m-d'); *