# how to select rows from a database in php where the date field is 7 days in the future

Tags: php, mysql

I have an automatic checker that checks for domains that are going to expire within the next 7 days and it sends and email to the customer.

Im using this SQL Query:

```
 $sql="SELECT * from domain_names where (status = '' or status = 'valid') and date(expiry_date) = date(now() + interval 7 day) ";
```

it works fine but if it stops running and a day goes past it wont do the domains it has missed. whats the best way to make it do the domains its missed too?

for example if a domain expires on 7th and it runs on the 1st it will see that domain and email the customer then put a flag on the row to say the email has already been sent but if the checker it not running on the 1st and it starts running again on the 2nd it wont see that domain (row)

Comment: Good idea, that flag thingie, so what exactly is the question?

Comment: it works fine but if it stops running and a day goes past it wont do the domains it has missed. whats the best way to make it do the domains its missed too?

Comment: Use a MySQL event to make it run every day on a schedule.

Comment: its running just on a web browser so if the power goes down or the internet goes down it wont run...

Comment: I gave yo uthe answer to this exact point in my answer to your previous exact question I'll give you a hint its todo with date diff being >= 0 and <=7 and a flag in your database.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Select from MySQL where date field is 7 days in the future](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366881/php-select-from-mysql-where-date-field-is-7-days-in-the-future)

Answer (score 1):

Just a little modification in the code of yours(Putting '<'):

```
$sql="SELECT * from domain_names where (status = '' or status = 'valid') and date(expiry_date) <= date(now() + interval 7 day) ";
```

Answer (score 0):

You are only checking for days exactly 7 days ahead. You want to check for up to 7 days ahead. Change your code to:

```
$sql="SELECT * from domain_names where (status = '' or status = 'valid') and date(expiry_date) <= date(now() + interval 7 day) ";
```

Since you have a flag any that have already been emailed within this period wont get e-mailed again.

Comment: thats doing ALL the rows in the database?

Answer (score 0):

You want to check where DATE is LESS THAN OR EQUAL TO (today + 7 days).

You should also have some sort of a "flag" in the table, such as `reminderSent` - so you don't send multiple reminders every time the query/script is ran.

```
$sql = "SELECT * from domain_names WHERE
  (status = '' or status = 'valid') AND 
  date(expiry_date) <= date(now() + interval 7 day) AND
  AND !reminderSent";
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a flag to indicate if an email has been sent. Simply Check flag status for all domains that are going to expire within the next 7 days.

And your query returns only the domains expiring a week from present.
Modify it to return domains expiring within the next 7 days.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you need to send the mail if its within the 7 day period OR has an incomplete flag.

I would however change the column from a string to an integer as it really only has two values `sent` or `not sent` i.e 1 or 0.

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  domain_names 
WHERE 
  status = 0 
OR 
  expiry_date BETWEEN NOW() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

In this case, providing you update the status field to 1 you will always be able to send next time when the script fails.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need some date interval like:

```
$sql="SELECT * from domain_names where (status = '' or status = 'valid') and date(expiry_date) between date(now()) and date(now() + interval 7 day)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a processed date to the record.  This is two fold, it gives you the processed flag, but it also gives you a historical reference for when the notification was sent.

In your query, add a condition that says processed_date is null, and the expiry_date is less than or equal to today plus 7 days.

```
(pseudo) where ...  and processed_date is null and expiry_date <= today + 7
```

When you're looking for records after a missed

Answer (score 0):

```
This should give the result as you need:

DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) = expiry_date;
You can refer to the link below for more details:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html
```

Answer (score 0):

Set up a CRON event on the server side, if your web host provides it. Then you can have it run as often as you want, without having to worry about power outages or internet outages.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this query. It will use full for you..

> $sql="SELECT * from domain_names where (status = '' or status =
>   'valid') and DATE_ADD( expiry_date, INTERVAL 7 DAY )";

Answer (score 0):

Or you could set it up in php using a variable in place of the current date plus 7 days such as;

```
$nextWeek=date("Ymd")+7;
$sql="SELECT * from domain_names where (status = '' or status = 'valid') 
and date(expiry_date) <= $nextWeek) ";
```

whatever date format you use , you'll need to swap `"Ymd"` if different, which is `20140621` as I write this  would translate to `20140628`.

lower case `m` and lower case `d` allow for two digit days and months `"06"` or `"01"`.
upper case I believe will change it to single digits....`2014621`
and you can change the order and put `"/"` or `"-"` as in:

> date("M-D-Y") +7 = 6-28-2014
>
> date("d/M/Y")+7 = 28/6/2014

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

```
$sql = SELECT * from domain_names where (status = '' or status = 'valid') and date(expiry_date) = DATE_ADD(date(now()), INTERVAL 7 DAY);
```

It may help you...

Answer (score 0):

have you considered adding a log of when yo last checked your expiry records and then using that date as your variable so you can check from that last date each time your code runs?