# PHP Mysql: find expired dates in table and extend them

Tags: php, mysql, date

PHP Mysql: find expired dates in table and extend them

Hi - I have a php classifieds site, would I go about running a command that will find the expired ads and automatically increase the dates by XX amount of days..

here is the structure

```
DATEBASE = "realestatedb"   
table names are 
"tt_44" to "tt_56"
```

Fieldname is `ExpireDate`  type is date

I have read .. [PHP Select from MySQL where date field is 7 days in the future](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17366881/php-select-from-mysql-where-date-field-is-7-days-in-the-future)

but could not figure it out

would this work

```
SELECT * 
  FROM realestatedb
  WHERE status IN('','ExpireDate')
   AND expiry_date = DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 7 DAY)
```

Comment: Why the field 'status'? And 'expiry_date' shouldn't be 'ExpireDate'?

Comment: I have no clue just learning .

Comment: Cool... kainaw's answer should work for you. DATE_ADD is the function you want, instead of only DATE.

Answer (score 0):

The MySQL function to add to a date is DATE_ADD. You use DATE_ADD(fieldname, INTERVAL 7 DAY) to add 7 days to the field.

You want to add some days to expired dates. By expired, I assume you mean that they are before a certain date. So, assume expired means before 2015-01-01. Then, you would use:

```
UPDATE tt_44 SET ExpireDate = DATE_ADD(ExpireDate, INTERVAL 7 DAY) where ExpireDate<'2015-01-01';
```

That would add 7 days to every date that comes before 2015-01-01 in the table tt_44

Comment: after UPDATE you name the tablename in your case it is _realestatedb_

Comment: I changed the table name to tt_44 to make it more obvious.

Comment: can any of you brains help me on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27805477/php-curl-session-cookie-ssl-login-error

Answer (score 0):

I had to run the command a few times so it updates all of them do you know why that is ..

```
mysql> UPDATE tt_44 SET ExpireDate = DATE_ADD(ExpireDate, INTERVAL 365 DAY) where ExpireDate<'2015-01-01';
Query OK, 72 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 72  Changed: 72  Warnings: 0

mysql> UPDATE tt_44 SET ExpireDate = DATE_ADD(ExpireDate, INTERVAL 365 DAY) where ExpireDate<'2015-01-01';
Query OK, 15 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 15  Changed: 15  Warnings: 0

mysql> UPDATE tt_44 SET ExpireDate = DATE_ADD(ExpireDate, INTERVAL 365 DAY) where ExpireDate<'2015-01-01';
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 3  Changed: 3  Warnings: 0

mysql> UPDATE tt_44 SET ExpireDate = DATE_ADD(ExpireDate, INTERVAL 365 DAY) where ExpireDate<'2015-01-01';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> UPDATE tt_44 SET ExpireDate = DATE_ADD(ExpireDate, INTERVAL 365 DAY) where ExpireDate<'2015-01-01';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> UPDATE tt_44 SET ExpireDate = DATE_ADD(ExpireDate, INTERVAL 365 DAY) where ExpireDate<'2015-01-01';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 0  Changed: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Comment: This adds 365 days to ExpireDate. If ExpireDate is more than 365 days before '2015-01-01', it will add 365 days, but it will still be before 2015-01-01.